# Deploy nextjs prisma to vercel from github actions

Tags: next.js, github-actions, prisma, vercel

I am building a nextjs 13 site on github actions and deploying statically to vercel. It usses prisma and I get this error in the runtime logs from vercel:

```
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  2022-12-12T01:07:00.196Z      2581999e-981c-4f05-a35d-f6f467934166   INFO     PrismaClientInitializationError: Query engine library for current platform "rhel-openssl-1.0.x" could not be found.
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  You incorrectly pinned it to rhel-openssl-1.0.x
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  This probably happens, because you built Prisma Client on a different platform.
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  (Prisma Client looked in "/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node")
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  Searched Locations:
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z    /var/task/node_modules/.prisma/client
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z    /home/runner/work/project1/project1/node_modules/@prisma/client
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z    /var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z    /var/task/node_modules/.prisma/client
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z    /var/task/node_modules/.prisma/client
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z    /tmp/prisma-engines
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z    /var/task/node_modules/.prisma/client
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  To solve this problem, add the platform "rhel-openssl-1.0.x" to the "binaryTargets" attribute in the "generator" block in the "schema.prisma" file:
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  generator client {
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z    provider      = "prisma-client-js"
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z    binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-3.0.x", "linux-arm64-openssl-1.1.x"]
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  }
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  Then run "prisma generate" for your changes to take effect.
2022-12-12T01:07:00.163Z  Read more about deploying Prisma Client: https://pris.ly/d/client-generator
```

This is what my schema file looks like:

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-3.0.x", "linux-arm64-openssl-1.1.x", "rhel-openssl-1.0.x"]
}
```

The only configuration I can find for my runtime on vercel is this:

[image]

Anybody know how I can change my github action environment to build for the vercel environment? What even is the vercel environment? I'm building in a runner that uses ubuntu-latest on github

Answer (score 2):

The error makes me think that you need to actually compile the Prisma client in Vercel, and not in GitHub Actions. That way you guarantee that the Prisma client is being compiled for the target platform (Vercel) and not for your CI/CD platform (GitHub Actions.)

These docs might help: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/deploying-to-vercel#vercel-build-hook

And they point to using this command in your `package.json` for building the client in Vercel:

```js
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "vercel-build": "prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy && next build",
    "prisma:generate": "prisma generate"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem fixed by following the instruction in the error message at added the platform *rhel-openssl-1.0.x* to the binaryTargets then ran `prisma generate` again

In your case would make sure to add *rhel-openssl-1.0.x* to the end of the array as you currently have it

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-3.0.x", "linux-arm64-openssl-1.1.x", "rhel-openssl-1.0.x"]
}
```

Then make sure to run `prisma generate` again

Comment: This fix works perfectly for AWS lambda! client files are visible in `node_modules/.prisma/client` after `prisma generate` command.